# Why Alter Table execution after mysql restart

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have read few work arounds / alternatives for alter table command in mysql. However, fastest way i have found is to restart mysql server (of course this is not what you want to do in production environment)

Is there any reason why alter table executes much faster after mysql restart

(This is on AWS EC2 micro instance -  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2 )

Answer (score 0):

1. no locks on table. Process doesn't need to wait;
2. less impact on disk because alter require a lot of disk usage.